# Removing li items with Button onClick

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js, react-dropzone

I'm trying to add an active "x" button to each li so that a user can click on it to remove the `li` from the list. I've added the button so that it appears with each list item, but I don't know what I would need to enter `onClick` to remove the corresponding li after clicking. Any suggestions?

```
<div>
  <h5 className="col-lg-4 mt-4">Selected Files</h5>
  <ul className="nobull text-sm">
    {files.map((file) => (
      <li key={file.path}>
        <Button className="ml-3" close />
        {file.path} - {(file.size / 1024).toFixed(1)} KB
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You likely need to add an `onClick` handler, pass some file identifier, and remove it from `files` state. Is the above snippet all you've tried so far? Can you provide a more comprehensive component code example so we can see where `files` is defined and how it may be updated?

Comment: can you please provide what `files` value is?

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone, after further research, I was able to get my answer. I created the following const:

```
  const remove = file => {
    const newFiles = [...files];     // make a var for the new array
    newFiles.splice(file, 1);        // remove the file from the array
    setFiles(newFiles);              // update the state
  };
```

Then I updated my code as such:

```
<div>
  <h5 className="col-lg-4 mt-4">Selected Files</h5>
  <ul className="nobull text-sm">
    {files.map((file, i) => (
      <li key={file.path} className="py-2">
        <Button className="ml-3" onClick={() => remove(i)} close />
        {file.path} - {(file.size / 1024).toFixed(1)} KB
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
</div>;
```

Comment: FYI, the idiomatic way to remove from an array is to use a functional update and filter the array, i.e. `setFiles(files => files.filter((el, i) => i !== index));`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
const handleDelete = (index) => {
    let filesArr = [...files];

    filesArr.splice(index, 1);      // This will delete the element

    // Update the state with this modified array
    setFiles(filesArr);     // like this
}

<div>
  <h5 className="col-lg-4 mt-4">Selected Files</h5>
  <ul className="nobull text-sm">
    {files.map((file, fileIndex) => (           // fileIndex is added here to hold array element index
      <li key={file.path}>
        <Button className="ml-3" close />
        {file.path} - {(file.size / 1024).toFixed(1)} KB
        <button type="button" onClick={() => handleDelete(fileIndex)}
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
</div>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the key array that you want to remove.

```
function Files(){
   const [dis, setDis] = useState([]);

   const removeHandler = (key) => {
     setDis(dis.push(key))
   }
   return(
     <div>
       <h5 className="col-lg-4 mt-4">Selected Files</h5>
       <ul className="nobull text-sm">
         {files.map((file, key) => (
           !fruits.includes(key) && (
             <li key={file.path}>
               <Button className="ml-3" close onClick={()={removeHandler(key)}}/>
               {file.path} - {(file.size / 1024).toFixed(1)} KB
              </li>
            )
          ))}
        </ul>
     </div>;
   )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  you could use a function like this  const removeFile = id =>{ const updatedFiles = files.filter(file => file.id !== FileId)
setFiles(updatedFiles)
```

}

<Button className="ml-3" onClick={() => removeFile(id)} close />